# Is Dijkstra algorithm informed or uninformed search strategies?

Tags: algorithm, graph, artificial-intelligence, binary-search-tree, heuristics

i need an explanation about Dijkstra algorithm since it is used for find shortest path by using value so it is informed search but in some references is uninformed search algorithm, so please clarify why it is uninformed search?

Comment: Look up A* search.

Comment: Adding on to what orlp has commented, there are both uninformed and informed *versions* of Dijkstra's Algorithm. To understand this fully, you'll first need to know that the algorithm constantly has to choose which node in a graph to process next. The textbook implementation of Djikstra's Algorithm always processes the node that is closest to the starting node based on already-calculated distances, but uses no other outside information (so it's uninformed). Variants of Dijkstra's Algorithms, like the well-known A* Algorithm, might use *heuristics* (informed search) as an optimization.